# Application non responsive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi Guys I have a winform which acts as an interface for a database.  At some point the user will select a directory which contains 30 to 40 files.  These files will have to be inserted into the database as raw data.  That is as is.  Then that raw data will interrupted and fixed up.  Once this is done the user can dump the fixed data to one excel file.  This works perfectly when I am running it in visual studios in release or debug mode.  However when I try to run it form outside of visual studios (that is from the bin / release file) it stalls then becomes non-responsive.  I and the user don't mind if it becomes slow (about 60 thousand records are printed).  However why does it stop working.  I figured the part where it stops responding and it doesn't seem like its deadlocked? Any ideas of how to improve it would be appreciated.    I also requested that my application runs with high priority but that still doesn't help.

Comment: Code would help.  Also when it stops does it throw an exception?

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing all the processing in the UI thread?

Comment: What is the UI thread ? I am sorry I just started working in C#.

Comment: You need to do the "work" of your application on a different thread than the one your GUI runs on.

Comment: I looked up an example I will change my object that does all the work to a thread and see what happens

Comment: [Basics on Threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Writer.dumpToExcel(getOUputLocation())));
               thread.Start();   ??????  Thanks swDevman81

Comment: @Jakub If a busy UI thread was the problem, it would happen in the debugger too.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman - depends on the amount of processing being done. If during development he processes only few records than he wouldn't notice.

Comment: @Jakub I think your right while development (debugging) i tested it processing about 60000 rows and no problem.  But here is my new solution I am working on.  Instead of reading each row from the table and processing them (the req is I read a users name map them to info and print it out) one at a time.  I created a crosstab query in access which does the mapping so that in c# I only read once from the db (run the query).  Then add them to an array and dump to xls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do all that processing in a separate thread. I would recommend using the BackgroundWorker.

Here is information about the class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Here is an example of how to use it - http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/04/04/implementing-multi-threading-in-winforms-using-the-backgroundworker-class/